# ReactNative queryString not formatting correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo, query-string

I am trying to fetch data based on a query. However, if i pass a query to my api call and format the queryString. The result will look like this:

```
Object {
  "DE": null,
  "limit": 10,
  "offset": 0,
}
```

When fomratted correctly, the Object should look like this:

```
Object {
  "query": "DE",
  "limit": 10,
  "offset": 0,
}
```

(For showcasing my issue I set a default value fro my query). My API call looks like this:

```
export function thunkFetchOrders(
    query = 'DE',
    offset = 0,
    limit = 10,
    filters = {}
) {
    return async (dispatch: any) => {

        if (offset === 0) {
            dispatch(
                resetOrders()
            )
        }
    
        let requestParams = {
            offset,
            limit,
        }

        requestParams = {...requestParams, ...setFilter(filters)}

        if (query) {
            requestParams = {...requestParams, ...queryString.parse(query)}
        }

        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`/orders`, {params: requestParams})

            await dispatch(
                fetchOrders(
                    res.data,
                    limit,
                    offset,
                    filters
                )
            )    
        }
        catch (error) {
            await dispatch(thunkFetchError(error));
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query-string library as it provide both parsing and stringify.
https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string